# Submitting an LSF script via python's subprocess.Popen() without shell=True

Tags: python, lsf

Forewarning, question is probably more about a lack of understanding of the `bsub` command and login shells than python's `Popen()`.

---

I am trying to submit a [LSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) script within a python script using `subprocess.Popen()`

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("bsub < script.lsf"),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It seems a subprocess is properly launched and the command executed, but I get an error in `stderr` from the bsub command that reads "Empty job. Job not submitted."

I was worried it had something to do with subprocess launching a login-shell, so I tried to use `shell=True` within the Popen command to alleviate that.

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("bsub < script.lsf", shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This successfully submits the job as expected. So my question is how can I submit this job without using `shell=True`?

---

I've tried using some [bsub options](http://www.vub.ac.be/BFUCC/LSF/bsub.1.html) such as

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("bsub -L /bin/sh < script.lsf"),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

with the same "Empty job. Job not submitted." error returned. I feel this is close to what I am looking for, but I don't fully understanding what "The name of the login shell (must specify  an  absolute path" is exactly. Perhaps it is not `/bin/sh` on the system I am using. Is there a way to print this path?

Comment: BTW, I'd argue that `shlex.split()` is really bad practice here. Not as dangerous as `shell=True`, sure, but `['yourcommand', '-f', filename]` is going to work with every possible filename, and `shlex.split('yourcommand -f %s' % filename)` won't (and for *some* commands, where extra arguments will be parsed as code, can still allow injection attacks).

Comment: If I am following, you say that somehow a user makes `filename = "file execute_bad_code"`, where the second command there "execute_bad_code" is an injection attack. So in `shlex.split('yourcommand -f %s' % "file execute_bad_code")` vs `['yourcommand', '-f', 'file execute_bad_code']`, `shlex.split()` runs the attack, while your method throws an error, preventing the attack?

Comment: well, not so much "throws an error" (in and of itself) as "passes an invalid filename to `yourcommand`, which `yourcommand` is responsible for seeing as an error" -- but that's much better than passing a separate argument `execute_bad_code` to `yourcommand`, which it might actually read as a valid argument and follow to perform the desired operation. If your command is `sed`, for instance, if you inject an `-e` followed by another argument, that other argument will be parsed as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` and `>` are not arguments to your command (in this case `bsub`), but are instructions to the shell about where stdin or stdout (respectively) should be directed before that command is started.

Thus, the appropriate replacement is to specify this redirection with a separate argument to `Popen`:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(['bsub', '-L', '/bin/sh'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=open('script.lsf', 'r'))
```